# Can't load assets or upload assets

Tags: assets, deployment

Currently trying to load an asset located in the following branch of my install:

- Craft

  - html

    - uploads

Unfortunately when I try to head directly to a specific asset I get the following error message from Craft:

```
You don't have permission to access /uploads/students/universities/giphy.gif on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

I've set the following on the uploads folder

```
chmod 774 /var/www/html/
```

My site is on DigitalOcean.

Any help would be brilliant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by doing the following commands:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
service apache2 restart
```